# SP2013: The link "Publish" is not working after I checked in a page

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

I am using sp2013. I have the OOTB pages list. When users add a new item they can save it and check it in. After you check the page in you see a yellow block with a message to publish the page. When I click on the link publish it is not working. Is this a bug or what?

[image]

In english:
Vitors can't see this page. Publish it.

Comment: What is not working ? Does he give an error ? Is the block grayed out ? Does he just not do the publish part ? Is it waiting for an approval workflow ?

Comment: It is doing nothing. No error, no popup. Nothing. I have also try it with compatibility mode but didnt help.

Comment: And it keeps indicating you still have to publish ? Are you using IE10 / IE 11 ? can you try putting it in IE9 and try again ? --- I've had similar situations happens to me in the latest IE on SP2013, where buttons calling JS didn't work.

Comment: The option to publish in the ribbon is working. But this link in the yellow block is also need to working. It is ootb functionality.

Comment: Also the check in link in the yellow block is working. The publish link is doing nothing.